# Distribution of fibers of Euler-Phi

Tags: nt.number-theory

Motivation: It's an elementary exercise to show that the number of solutions to the equation  $\phi(x)=n$ is finite for any $n$, where $\phi$ is the Euler-phi function. Of course, counting the number of solutions is another matter.

Question: For a given $n$, can we describe the number of solutions to  $|\phi^{-1}(n)|=m$?  In other words, I want to know about how often the number of solutions to the equation $\phi(x)=n$ is $m$, for a given $m$, as $n$ varies. Since it wouldn't surprise me if this is way too hard, can we at least say something similar about finiteness?

Comment: Proving that your number is always non-zero is already pretty hard. This reference will get you going: K. Ford, The number of solutions of $\phi(x)=m$ , Annals of Math. 150 (1999), 283--311.

Comment: Yours is the totient valence function, and it is a result of Erdős dating back to 1958 that if for some $m$ there exists at least one $n$ such that $|\phi^{-1}(n)|=m$ then $|\phi^{-1}(n)|=m$ for infinitely many $n$; see P. Erdős, *Some Remarks on Euler's $\phi$-Function,* Acta Math. (1958), Vol. 4, pp. 10-19.

Comment: To add something to Felipe's comment, the question is related to a long-standing conjecture, mostly referred to as *Carmichael's totient function conjecture*, with a story behind it: Carmichael had published an alleged proof (Carmichael, *On Euler's $\phi$-Function,* Bull. AMS, Vol. 13 (1907), pp. 241-243), and even developed a method of finding a solution for each m (R.D. Carmichael, *Notes on the Simplex Theory of Numbers,* Bull. AMS, Vol. 15 (1909), pp. 217-223), to the extent of proposing the question as an exercise in his 1914 monograph on the theory of numbers. It took more than... (TBC)

Comment: ...a decade before Carmichael himself realized an error in his earlier "proof" (R.D. Carmichael, *Note on Euler's $\phi$-Function,* Bull. AMS, Vol. 28 (1922), pp. 109-110), with the result that the question is still today broadly open. In spite of the fact that Dickson, in the 2005 edition of his *History of the Theory of Numbers* (Vol. 1, p. 137), states that the conjecture was proved in Carmichael's original 1907 paper. 

Comment: @Salvo, to be fair to Dickson, that volume was published in 1919. The later "editions" are unaltered reprints of the 1919 text. 